# How do I update data frame fields in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm looking to update fields in one data table with information from another data table like this:

```
dt1$name <- dt2$name where dt1$id = dt2$id

In SQL pseudo code : update dt1 set name = dt2.name where dt1.id = dt2.id
```

As you can see I'm very new to R so every little helps.

**Update**
I think it was my fault - what I really want is to update an telephone number if the usernames from both dataframes match.

So how can I compare names and update a field if both names match?
Please help :)

```
dt1$phone<- dt2$phone where dt1$name = dt2$name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joran's answer assumes `dt1` and `dt2` can be matched by position.

If it's not the case, you may need to `merge()` first:

```
dt1 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3), name = c("a", "b", "c"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dt2 <- data.frame(id = c(7, 3), name = c("f", "g"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dt1 <- merge(dt1, dt2, by = "id", all.x = TRUE)
dt1$name <- ifelse( ! is.na(dt1$name.y), dt1$name.y, dt1$name.x)
dt1
```

(Edit per your update:

```
dt1 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3), name = c("a", "b", "c"), phone = c("123-123", "456-456", NA), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dt2 <- data.frame(name = c("f", "g", "a"), phone = c(NA, "000-000", "789-789"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dt1 <- merge(dt1, dt2, by = "name", all.x = TRUE)
dt1$new_phone <- ifelse( ! is.na(dt1$phone.y), dt1$phone.y, dt1$phone.x)
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it's exactly the same thing, with `name` instead of `id` and `phone` instead of `name`. See my edit

Comment: Thanks for the code, it really helped solve my problem. I appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
dt1$name <- ifelse(dt1$id == dt2$id, dt2$name, dt1$name)
```

Alternatively, maybe:

```
dt1$name[dt1$id == dt2$id] <- dt2$name[dt1$id == dt2$id]
```

Comment: @jordan: Thanks for your answer but it looks to work only when dt1 and dt2 can be matched by position. The position in both dataframes cannot always be expected to be at the same position so I would like them to match by name in this case where the names from both match. Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're more comfortable working in SQL, you can use the `sqldf` package:

```
dt1 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3),
                  name = c("A", "B", "C"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dt2 <- data.frame(id = c(2, 3, 4),
                  name = c("X", "Y", "Z"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(sqldf)

sqldf("SELECT dt1.id, 
        CASE WHEN dt2.name IS NULL THEN dt1.name ELSE dt2.name END name
      FROM dt1
        LEFT JOIN dt2
          ON dt1.id = dt2.id")
```

But, computationally, it's about 150 times slower than joran's solution, and quite a bit slower in the human time as well.  However, if you are ever in a bind and just need to do something that you can do easily in SQL, it's an option.